# Merge sort in C

Tags: c, algorithm, mergesort

I am new in programming/C. 
I understand the algorithm of merge-sort as an algorithm but when it comes to programming, it appears that I am doing something wrong. 
Could anybody help?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
merge(int A[],int p,int q,int r);
part(int A[],int p,int r);

int main()
{
int A [6]={10,5,4,0,11,7}, n,y,z;

y=1; z=sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);

part(A,y,z);
for(n=0;n<z;n++)
printf("%d\n", A[n]);

    return 0;
}

part(int A[],int p,int r)
{
    if (p<r)
    {
        int q=(p+r)/2;
        part(A,p,q);
        part(A,q+1,r);
        merge(A,p,q,r);
    }
}

merge(int A[],int p,int q,int r)
{
    int n1=q-r+1,n2=r-q,L[n1+1],R[n2+1],i,j,k;
    L[n1+1]=100000;
    R[n2+1]=100000;
    for (i=0;i<n1;i++)
        L[i]=A[p-1+i];
    for (j=0;j<n2;j++)
        R[j]=A[q+j];
    i=0;j=0;
    for (k=0;k<r;k++)
        if(L[i]<=R[j])
    {
        A[k]=L[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        A[k]=R[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `it appears that I am doing something wrong.` what happens that makes you think so?

Comment: How you came to this conclusion that `I am doing something wrong`?

Comment: You can start by specifying the return type of your functions.

Comment: First: arrays, in C, have indexes from `0` to `n - 1`. An array defined as `int L[n1 + 1];` has (`n1 + 1`) elements with indexes `0` to `n1`. The element `L[n1 + 1]` does not exist ... yet you attempt to write to it.

Comment: For all the sarcastic comments `what happens that makes you think so?`, `How you came to this conclusion` - if the OP knew the answer to this the question would never have been asked. The OP tried to solve a problem and posted the effort in question. If you cannot answer questions then don't take the standard of SO down at least. I expect SO to answer such questions as an experienced user here. Same for the downvoters. We know exactly what Merge Sort is supposed to do.

Comment: @al-Acme - failing to provide output, logs, error-messages and whatever has been found so far by the OP's debugging attempts is a waste of contributors' time.  The OP obviously didn't think that such a waste was important.  That's fine, but it's then not surprising that contributors can't be bothered with wasting any effort on such a question.  Then there's the code, with its single-letter vars and no comments.  I ignore such code - there are more interesting and fruitful questions that don't involve un-obfuscating someone else's crap before attempting to spot bugs.

Comment: There is no output required. Output is what Merge sort should give, the code is invoking UB and at times may have no runtime errors even. And if it is such a waste of time to read this question - then why waste time commenting on it.

Comment: @al-Acme - you did, and then criticised contributors for asking a reasonable question: to explain 'it appears that I am doing something wrong'.  I haven't looked closely at the code, just the comments.  The OP question is debugging-slave request.  It deserves to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your corrected code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

void merge(int A[],int p,int q,int r);
void part(int A[],int p,int r);

int main()
{
int A [6]={10,5,4,0,11,7}, n,y,z;

y=0; z=6;

part(A,0,z-1); // Pass starting from 0 to Length - 1 of Array
for(n=0;n<z;n++)
printf("%d\n", A[n]);

    return 0;
}

void part(int A[],int p,int r)
{
    if (p<r)
    {
        int q=(p+r)/2;
        part(A,p,q);
        part(A,q+1,r);
        merge(A,p,q,r);
    }
}

void merge(int A[],int p,int q,int r)
{
    int n1=q-p+1,n2=r-q;
    int L[n1+1],R[n2+1],i,j,k;
    L[n1]=INT_MAX;
    R[n2]=INT_MAX;

    for (i=0;i<n1;i++)
        L[i]=A[p+i];

    for (j=0;j<n2;j++)
        R[j]=A[q+j+1];

    i=0;j=0;

    for (k=p;k<=r;k++)
    {
        if(L[i]<=R[j])
        {
            A[k]=L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            A[k]=R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

These are the parts which were wrong:

```
int n1=q-r+1,n2=r-q  // --> Your calculation of new indices was wrong
```

These indices take you out of bounds of the array:

```
L[n1+1]=100000;
R[n2+1]=100000;
```

Also instead of using a random value like `100000` use `INT_MAX` in `limits.h` for the sentinel element.

```
 for (k=0;k<r;k++) // ->wrong
```

You should move from left index of array to right not from `0`th index.

Output:

```
0
4
5
7
10
11
```

Rest you can check for yourself.

Comment: The code did not work - that's quite a strong indication that i was doing something wrong. Thanks **al-Acme**

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution with part parameters 0 to size of array. My old C compiler doesn't support variable sized arrays so I used _alloca() as a substitute. Other alternatives would be to pass a second array to be used as a temp array for the merge sort, and either a top down or bottom up merge sort. The copy operations can be avoided in top down by alternating the direction of the merge based on the level of recursion, with a pair of co-recursive functions: the top level would be partAtoA(), which would call partAtoB() (which would call partAtoA(), ...).

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int A[],int p,int q,int r);
void part(int A[],int p,int r);

int main()
{
int A[6]={10,5,4,0,11,7}, n,y,z;
    y=0;
    z=sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);
    part(A,y,z);
    for(n=0;n<z;n++)
        printf("%d\n", A[n]);
    return 0;
}

void part(int A[], int p, int r)
{
int q;
    if ((r - p) < 2)
        return;
    q=(p+r)/2;
    part(A,p,q);
    part(A,q,r);
    merge(A,p,q,r);
}

void merge(int A[],int p,int q,int r)
{
int n1=q-p, n2=r-q;
int i,j,k;
/* using _alloca for variable size arrays */
int * L = _alloca(n1*sizeof(int));
int * R = _alloca(n2*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<n1; i++)
        L[i]=A[p+i];
    for (j=0; j<n2; j++)
        R[j]=A[q+j];
    i=0;j=0;
    for(k=p;k<r;k++)
        if(j>=n2 || i<n1 && L[i]<=R[j])
            A[k]=L[i++];
        else
            A[k]=R[j++];
}
```